MS office outlook addin js assets not being updated when deployed
I tried updating the the addin code. I believe ms caches some of these assets but I have waited multiple days and tried multiple redeployments. To this day I believe that the code still hasn't been updated due to incorrect url requests still being present.
I have tried redeploying the addin and updating the code multiple times without success. I could tell because the url requests we're still wrong. I have also tried updating the addin ID in the manifest and that didn't work either.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
